# SocialAuth 3.2 Twitter Error

Tags: android, twitter, socialauth, android-twitter

I am working on a project that uses the SocialAuth 3.2 Android library to connect to a bunch of social networks. All social networks work except for twitter. When I try to connect to twitter I get the following error:

"org.brickred.socialAuth.exception.SocialAuthConfigurationException?-Application keys are not correct.The server running the application should be same as that was registered to get the keys. "

There is a lot of web posting about this error. For most people the solution involved filling in the callback URL on the twitter API page. I have set the callback URL on the API page and used the same URL for connecting as follows

```
adapter.addCallback(Provider.TWITTER, "http://callback.app.com");
adapter.authorize(context, Provider.TWITTER);
```

I have also tried to connect to twitter using the example applications provided in the SDK and cannot connect from those apps (which are provided by the library creator) either.

Any suggestions? I dont know if there are any known issues with this library or if anyone using version 3.2 has successfully connected to twitter and can help.

Comment: Getting similar issue for linkedin. Is it resolved for you? how you resolved it?

Comment: I never tried this with linkedin sorry

Answer (score 1):

So after some digging in the API the issue is related to the time and timezone set on the device. If you have a device that is not connected to a wireless network the time and timezone for your location need to be correct. Changing these settings manually for my Samsung Note on 4.2.2 fixed the problem.